# FabricJS IText - How to Add Textbox with Multiple Styles?

Tags: fabricjs

I have seen examples of how to apply multiple styles to a given IText object on a per line, per character basis using this syntax...

```
var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: 80 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
      4: { fontSize: 20 }
    }
  }
});
```

Fiddle here-
https://jsfiddle.net/tLy9eqj6/

Is there a similar syntax to set multiple characters within one line using only one set of arguments? For example this would underline the first 5 characters of line 1...

```
var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
styles: {
    0: {
      [0,1,2,3,4]: { textDecoration: 'underline' }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not (yet).

As of now, fabricjs has per style character or fallback on default style properties.

What you can do is optimize your style figuring out which is the most used style of your text, assign this to the IText Object and then style just the few characters differently.